# SharePoint Document Library Subscription Errors

Tags: 2010, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I have SSRS 2012 setup in SharePoint Integrated mode. I am receiving the following error when trying to setup a subscription to a SharePoint Document Library.

> A delivery error has occurred. --->
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.DeliveryErrorException:
>   A delivery error has occurred. --->
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InvalidExtensionParameter:
>   One of the extension parameters is not valid for the following reason:
>   The delivery path is either not a SharePoint Document Library Folder
>   or does not exist in the Share Point farm.

ULS Logs report the following:

> Detected use of SPRequest for previously closed SPWeb object.  Please close SPWeb objects > when you are done with all objects obtained from them, but not before.

Email subscriptions work without issue.

Comment: What else are you seeing in the Windows Event Logs and in the ULS when you attempt to subscribe? Have you used ULSLogViewer while subscribing?

Comment: There is nothing reported in the Windows Event Logs. ULS logs information was added to the problem description. 

I am attempting out of the box functionality, not any custom code.

Comment: Can you paste here (without the domain) the url you put in as the document library location?

Comment: http://<domain>/teams/ASD/ArchivedReports

Comment: do you have your sql agent service running as the sharepoint service account?

Comment: Yes, the SQL Server Agent is running/logged on as SharePoint Service SQL Agent account.

Comment: and that sharepoint service sql agent account has full control access to your web application that hosts the document library that you are trying to put the report into?

Comment: Adding the SQL Server Agent account with Full Control access produces the same error.

Answer (score 1):

> You can create a subscription that delivers a document based on the
>   original report to a library within the same SharePoint site as the
>   original report. You cannot deliver the document to a library on
>   another server or another site within the same site collection. To
>   deliver the document, you must have Add Items permission on the
>   library to which the report is delivered.

i would like to note "**you cannot deliver the document to a library on
 another server or another site within the same site collection**"

if the above is ok than you need to make sure you follow this:

> 1.
>
> Point to the report in a library.
>
> 2.
>
> Click the down arrow next to the report, and select Manage
>   Subscriptions.
>
> 3.
>
> Click Add Subscription.
>
> 4.
>
> In Delivery Extension, select SharePoint Document Library.
>
> 5.
>
> In Document Library, select a library within the same site.
>
> 6.
>
> In File Options, specify the file name and title for the document that
>   will be created by the subscription.
>
> 7.
>
> In Output Format, select the application format.
>
> Web archive (MHTML) is the default because it produces a
>   self-contained HTML file, but it will not preserve interactive report
>   features that might be in the original report.
>
> 8.
>
> In Overwrite Options, specify an option that determines whether
>   subsequent deliveries overwrite a file. If you want to preserve
>   previous deliveries, you can select Create a file with a unique name.
>   A number will be appended to new files to create a unique file name.
>
> 9.
>
> In Delivery Event, specify a schedule or event that causes the
>   subscription to run. You can create a custom schedule, select a shared
>   schedule if one is available, or run the subscription whenever the
>   data is refreshed for a report that runs with snapshot data.
>
> 10.
>
> In Parameters, if you are creating a subscription to a parameterized
>   report, specify the values that you want to use with the report when
>   the subscription is processed. The parameters section is not visible
>   on this page if the report you select does not contain parameters.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb283186(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I have followed the above steps and continue to receive the same error.

The document library is within the same site collection.

My login is also a farm and site collection admin.

Comment: ok so your setup should be correct.... im gonna go with somthing has gone wrong with your permission level! have you setup your ssrs correctly? and using the correct account that has read and execute on the sql database? follow this link, i know it says 2013 just ignor that part but do part 1 and 2! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219067.aspx

Comment: the key here is you follow it to the letter! also another issue is the account that you should create- it also needs to be within the local domain admin group and have access to SQL server with read and write permission!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to have to dig a little deeper in the ULS logs.  The entry you listed above doesn't apply to this issue you are having.  You might want to turn on the dev dashboard and then go through the clicks of subscribing to generate the error.  Then you can use the dev dashboard to get a better sense of the ULS entries that apply to your action.